# Arviz and Bokeh: Trying to change the title of the plot using backend kwargs

Tags: python, bokeh, pymc3, arviz

I am trying to change the title of the plot I'm creating with Arviz. Usually I have done this using the `backend_kwargs` but it doesn't seem to work for certain plots: in this case the `plot_density`.

This is the code i'm using:

```
kwg = dict(title="prior_1", height=500)
plot = az.plot_density(
                   data_m[0], 
                   group='posterior', 
                   var_names='switchpoint', 
                   backend='bokeh',
                   shade=.5, 
                   backend_kwargs=kwg
                   )
```

It recognises the height change in the `kwargs` so its not like its not picking up on them being there.

I have also tried other variations such as `plot_title=` and it will produce an error specifying it needs to be `title=`

Comment: This seems like something you might should open an issue on the arviz tracker about.

Comment: Do you have multiple subplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArviZ initializes Bokeh [Plot](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot) instances using the alias [figure](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.figure). As you can see reading the docs on `Plot`, `title` is a valid argument. For several reasons however, ArviZ does not use this argument when creating the plots, it sets the title afterwards. Thus, your argument is being recognized and used only to be overwritten.

`plot_density` sets the title of each plot to the variable name and, if multidimensional, its coordinates. Moreover, in addition to multiple variables (each of which can be multidimensional), it also supports plotting multiple models (thus different `InferenceData` objects) at the same time. You can use the argument `data_labels` to set the legend labels. An example of this can be seen in [ArviZ's example gallery](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/examples/bokeh/bokeh_plot_density.html), you can even click on the legend to hide models.

Therefore, to achieve the desired result, you have to manually modify the title after calling `plot_density`, which can be done with a couple extra lines. You have to call `plot_density` with `show=False` so that the figure can be modified afterwards. Then the title can be edited from the elements stored in the array returned by `plot_density`.

```
kwg = dict(height=500)
axes = az.plot_density(
    data_m[0],
    group="posterior",
    var_names="switchpoint",
    backend="bokeh",
    shade=0.5,
    backend_kwargs=kwg,
    show=False
)
axes[0,0].title.text = "prior_1"
az.plots.backends.show_layout(axes)
```

If you had multiple plots with several multidimensional variables you would have to edit the title for each one by looping over the array.